# How to create a document for all methods/class under Nunit project

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nunit

I am currently working on the Selenium Nunit Testing using C# with VS code.

We are following page object model.

We just wanted to list down all the methods and class in a document or web page (localhost) like how api document look like ..

How to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear, you are looking for some way to document all the classes/methods that make up your page object model?

That doesn't have anything to do with selenium or nunit. Just document your C# code with XML documentation comments like this:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// This class does something.
/// </summary>
public class SomeClass
{
}
```

Then use a tool like [DocFX](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/) or [Sandcastle](https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB) to generate HTML pages for your documentation.

From Microsoft (emphasis mine):

> XML documentation comments are a special kind of comment, added above the definition of any user-defined type or member. They are special because they can be processed by the compiler to generate an XML documentation file at compile time. The compiler-generated XML file can be distributed alongside your .NET assembly so that **Visual Studio and other IDEs can use IntelliSense to show quick information about types or members**. Additionally, the XML file can be run through tools like DocFX and Sandcastle to **generate API reference websites**.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/codedoc